# How Windows' file system keep association between files and folder

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, filesystems

I have a doubt. In Linux everything is file, and using inode Linux maintains association between files and folder. But in Windows folder is not a file (may be I am wrong), so how it is possible to map file and folder. Where association information is kept in Windows OS.

Thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing levels of abstraction. Sure, in Linux, `/dev/null` looks like a file, since it can be accessed with file API's.That doesn't mean it has an inode.

In reverse, on Windows (NTFS) folders are quite similar to files, except that the file API's refuse to operate on folders. The OS internally understands the similarity, though.

Comment: so should I say , 'In Windows everything is file'?

Comment: @user2481987: No, I've got no idea where that's coming from. Sockets are definitely not files on Windows.

Comment: Kindly note that, I am asking these questions just to understand difference between kernel implementation of Windows and Linux. Isn't it possible in Windows Socket is also file (internally). Because as far as I know WinSock APIs are almost similar to Berkeley Sockets.

Comment: @user2481987 No, sockets in Windows are user-mode entity. In kernel mode the architecture is different.